# Miktex update and Process Crashed on Texwork

Tags: miktex, windows, texworks

I have just updated miktex (on windows 10) this morning and I obtain an error with texwork when I compile a simple document as this one

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
\end{document}
```

When I compile with pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex I obtain

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/test/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02>
L3 programming layer <2020-02-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def")
No file test.aux.
[1{C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (test.aux
) )<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12438 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/test/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02>
L3 programming layer <2020-02-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def")
(test.aux) [1{C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
] (test.aux) )<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10
.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12438 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.

Process crashed
```

When I compile only with pdflatex it works but I have no references ...
An idea ?

Comment: well your example doesn't have references, why do expect them? Beside this your log doesn't show any error and it is unclear what doesn't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer with a document with references I have also "Process Crashed" when I launch a compilation. I have not this error before this morning update ...

Comment: I can confirm that this seems to be a regression bug: `texify --pdf test.tex` works. But `%ERRORLEVEL%` is not zero and so TeXworks deduces an error condition.

Comment: @ChristianSchenk how to correct it ? (to compile through texwork on miktex+windows 10)

Comment: @AlBundy: a fixed executable can be downloaded from miktex.org:

http://download.miktex.org/tmp/25431947-168e-4556-a4a3-3db89dc7c203/texify.exe

This must be installed in the directory which contains the MiKTeX executables: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`

Comment: By the way: always be extra careful when downloading executables via obscure links. You should verify that the downloaded executable is not malware before you run it.